# What is the order of saving objects of a Model class?

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, spring-data-jpa, reactive-mongo-java

I have an POJO class for a JSON as follows:

```
public class Portcall {

   private Long id;
   .
   .

   PreviousPortCall previousPortCall;

   NextPortCall nextPortCall;

   .
}
```

Here all the 3 classes-PortCall, PreviousPortCall, NextPortCall are annotated with @Document.
Any change in PortCall.java will have effect on its immediate previous and next object as well which are referred by PreviousPortCall  and NextPortCall
In case I update the PortCall.java in Mongo DB, which order do I save the objects? Shall I save PreviousPortCall  and NextPortCall and then go for saving PortCall.java or vice versa and why?

Comment: read rules writing questions, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save an object of `Portcall`, the complete state of the object is stored into the database. So if your fields `previousPortCall` and `nextPortCall` are defined as `@Entity` as well, they will be stored automatically as the are part of the state of the `Portcall` instance. You don't need to save them explicitly at all.

Secondly: As long as you store multiple objects within the same `Transaction`, the order of storing does not matter, as the complete state will be atomicly visible in the database when the transaction is committed.